# iText 7 PDF parser returns unreadable characters in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, pdf, itext

I am trying to extract text from PDF files using iText 7 (the latest version). When I run the code below it extracts the text from every PDF I give it except the ones from a client (of course). They have a very old accounting system and the PDF files return unreadable text (diamonds w/question marks).

I can load their PDF files into Adobe Reader and copy/paste the text into notepad perfectly. Their PDFs are created by Ghostscript and the PDF file version is 1.7.

I have used iText many times and I have never encountered this before. The commented out line below was my attempt to see if it was some sort of encoding problem. I am coding in C# w/VS2019 and I installed iText 7 via Nuget. Thank you for your time!

```
        string fileName = @"c:\users\default\desktop\test\invoice.pdf";

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            PdfDocument pdfReader = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(fileName));
            for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.GetNumberOfPages(); page++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                String currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader.GetPage(page), strategy);
                //currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));

                outputtextBox.AppendText(currentText);
            }
            pdfReader.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Well... the first place to start, would be to ask you to upload the file, so that other people can examine what kind of funky stuff is going on in the file. But because it is a file from a client, you are probably not allowed to do that, which makes support on Stack Overflow close to impossible for this question. Are you by any chance a customer of iText Software? If you have a support contract, then all files you send, will be treated confidentially, and are automatically deleted 30 days after closure of a support case.

Comment: We can make educated guesses, but there is no way to be sure without actually seeing the file. I hope that you can understand that.

Comment: Just like @Amedee says, for helping seriously with issues which only occur for a few pdfs, one needs an example of such pdfs. Does the producer of that *old accounting system* probably have some example files on his web site? If he does and those files similarly fail in text extraction, you may share a link there.